Were there any criticisms of his first FTA proof during Gauss's lifetime?
According to several papers related to Gauss' FTA proof, in the first proof he said, “It seems to be well demonstrated that an algebraic curve neither ends abruptly (as it happens in the transcendental curve y = 1/ log x), nor lose itself after an infinite number of windings in a
point (like a logarithmic spiral). As far as I know nobody has ever
doubted this, but if anybody requires it, I take it on me to present,
on another occasion, an indubitable proof.” Even though he said that, he didn't provide the evidence in the end. So, was there no criticism of the his first FTA proof during Gauss' lifetime?

It is very difficult to ever definitively claim that something was not criticized in a substantial time interval (here we talk 1799-1855). However, my short answer would be "no", meaning I am unaware of any criticism of Gauss's proves of the fundamental theorem of algebra.
While not demonstrating this, a very germane primary source is Gauss's letter to Bolyai December 16, 1799 (see F. Schmidt, P. Stäckel (eds.) (1899). Briefwechsel zwischen Carl Friedrich Gauss und Wolfgang Bolyai. BG Teubner. p. 36ff).
I believe that much of the letter is of interest but given the length probably being beyond the scope of a sensible HoSM answer I will limit myself to citing sources in English discussing the parts I will omit.
The letter shows clearly that Gauss was aware that his dissertation was essentially a critique of how mathematics was done before him and aware and concerned with the reaction to that charge. (From personal experience this can indeed go poorly!) After all he was criticizing esteemed predecessors as well as contemporaries.
A good English translation or characterizations of the content of interesting parts of the letter can be found in two sources:

Dunnington, G. W. (1935). Gauss, His Disquisitiones Arithmeticae, and
His Contemporaries in the Institut de France. National Mathematics
Magazine, 9(7), 187-192. (see p.188f.)

Tent, M. B. (2006). The Prince of Mathematics: Carl Friedrich Gauss.
AK Peters/CRC. p.120f (The translation is only a trunctated translation of the letter).


Gauss writes about public reception and his distribution of his thesis:

Öffentliche "Urtheile darüber sind meines Wissens noch nirgends
erschienen. Ausgetheilt habe ich bis jetzt einige dreissig Exemplare,
theils an Mathematiker theils an solche denen ich aus Höflichkeit
eines schuldig war.


Public judgements about it have to my knowledge not appeared yet. I distributed about 30 copies, partly to mathematicians, partly to to those whom I owed one for reasons of politeness. (my translation)

As noted by Dunningworth, Gauss explicitly mentions nothing having been sent to France. After all Gauss had critiqued important French predecessors such as d'Alembert and the still living Lagrange.
In the letter he talks about having sent his dissertation to some 30 people, including one German compendium author von Tempelhoff who was at least implicitly included in Gauss's critique. Gauss writes to Bolyai:

Von Privaturtheilen die zu meiner Wissenschaft gekommen sind ist mir
nur vorzüglich das vom General von Tempelhoff in Berlin wichtig, und
hat mich um so mehr gefreut da er einer der besten deutschen
Mathematiker ist und besonders, da meine Vorwürfe ihn selbst, als den
Verfasser eines Compendiums, mit trafen. Aus der dritten Hand habe ich
erfahren dass er so darüber geimheilt hat: (es sind seine eignen
Worte) «der Gauss ist ein ganz verzweifelter Mathematiker; er gibt
auch nicht eine Handbreit Terrain nach ; er hat brav und gut gefochten
und das Schlachtfeld vollkommen behauptet.»


For private judgements about my science, I so far only hold important the one of General von Tempelhoff of Berlin, and it has made my very happy that he is one of the best German mathematicians and especially, because my criticisms included him personally, as the author of a compendium. From third hand I learned that he gave the following evaluation: (these are his own words) «this Gauss is a totally desperate mathematician; he does not give up a hand-widths worth of terrain; he fought hard and brave and has completely won the battlefield.» (my translation)

So Gauss got some positive confirmation that his argument might be received positively. I do not know if Gauss ever sent his dissertation to Lagrange, who is probably the most prominent living person of the ones he criticized.
In many ways it is Gauss who is the critic in the 1799 dissertation demanding more rigor and a new look at mathematics. Dunningworth's article linked above gives some indication about Gauss's reception in France and suggests that he was accepted rather quickly, following the contemporaneous reporting of Alexander von Humbold.
The question of critique is an intriguing one. Even post-death I have not been able to find any concern pre-Ostrowski's 1920 proof. Klein in his Entwicklungen presents Gauss's four proofs uncritically. Even Dunnington's biography of 1955 presents Gauss's work on FTA as four proofs (The 2004 reissue contains additional material by Gray and Dohse. Note the first paragraph of the Annotated Bibliography of this edition contains a critical evaluation of both Gauss's 1799 proof and his critique of d'Alembert's, written by Gray, as well as historian's more critical view of the situation since Dunnington's original). As a final note, Dunnington's article also contains a story of Bertrand, a translator of Gauss pointing out what he taught as an error in Gauss's work and Gauss's reaction to criticism.


I regret not definitively answering the question, because no matter how much I searched, I found no record of any real criticism of Gauss for this. There is a strong reason for this criticism not to exist, as Gauss himself used a conjecture and expressly said that it lacked proof.
In his doctoral thesis, when Gauss was just 22 years old, he "proved" the fundamental theorem only for polynomials with real coefficients. One can easily deduce from this the fundamental theorem of algebra for complex coefficients. The proof depended only on a banal fact, which he thought he could prove in a few days.
It's quite intuitive. An algebraic curve in the complex plane enters a disk around the origin. Can we guarantee that the curve will come out of the disk? It really seemed like a trivial detail.
Smale (1981)
Given a polynomial f of degree N > 0 with real coefficients, Gauss considered the algebraic curves in the plane defined by the equations Re(f(z)) = 0 and Im(f(z)) = 0.

Curves  $ \text{Re}(f(z)) = 0  $ and  $ \text{Im}(f(z)) = 0  $:

These curves represent the points in the complex plane where the real part and the imaginary part of  $ f(z)  $ are zero, respectively.


Behavior of the Curves:

Each curve consists of several continuous branches. Gauss showed that for sufficiently large  $ r  $, each of these curves intersects the circle  $ |z| = r  $ at exactly  $ 2N  $ points (where  $ N  $ is the degree of the polynomial).




Attempts to prove the fundamental theorem began with d’Alembert (1746), and that the first satisfactory proof was given by Gauss (1799). This opinion should not be accepted without question, as the source of it is Gauss himself. Gauss (1799) gave a critique of proofs from d’Alembert on, showing that they all had serious weaknesses, then offered a proof of his own. His intention was to convince readers that the new proof was the first valid one, even though it used one unproved assumption .... The opinion as to which of two incomplete proofs is more convincing can of course change with time, and I believe that Gauss (1799) might be judged differently today. We can now fill the gaps in d’Alembert (1746) by appeal to standard methods and theorems, whereas there is still no easy way to fill the gap in Gauss (1799).
Gauss, in his thesis, write about the conjecture as follows (thesis translated into English from the Latin in Struik):
"Now it is known from higher geometry that every algebraic curve (or the single parts of an algebraic curve when it happens to consist of several parts) either runs into itself or runs out to infinity in both directions, and therefore if a branch of an algebraic curve enters into a limited space, it necessarily has to leave it again."7  . . . and  7[footnote by Gauss], "It seems to be sufficiently well demonstrated that an algebraic curve can neither be suddenly interrupted (as e.g. occurs with the transcendental curve with equation y = 1 /log x), not lose itself after an infinite number of terms (like the logarithmic spiral), and nobody, to my knowledge, has ever doubted it. But if anybody desires it, then on another occasion I intend to give a demonstration which will leave no doubt. . . ."
In fact even though Gauss redid this proof 50 years later, the gap remained. Gauss died on February 2 of 1855. Just in the 1920,  Alexander Ostrowski proved the conjecture. (Basu & Velleman, 2017).
References
Basu, S. and Velleman, D. (2017). On Gauss's first proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra.
Gauss, C. (2011). Werke..
Sangwin, C. (2019). Textbook accounts of the rules of indices with rational exponents. International Journal of Mathematical Education in Science and Technology, 50(8), 1191-1209.
Smale, S. (1981). The fundamental theorem of algebra and complexity theory. Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society, 4(1), 1–37.

Your answer begins with “Indeed, during Gauss' lifetime, there were criticisms of his first proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra (FTA).” However, you mention no specific example of such a criticism. Besides, what is that paragraph concerning the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic doing here?

373 / 5,000
Thank you very much for your careful reading! In fact, you are right. I wrote getting excited about the problem and forgot what was being asked. I'll try to correct it, otherwise I'll delete the answer. As for the alien paragraph, it really came by mistake, it was from an abandoned text trying to look for rudiments of abstract algebra in Gauss relating the two.
